# how to merge two list without including the element common in both list in python

Tags: python, list, append

`list1= ['ALEX', 'George', 'shyam']`

`list2= ['George','Ram', 'shyam']`

`output=['Alex', 'George','Shyam','Ram']`

I tried like it.

```
    list1=['ALEX', 'George', 'shyam']
    list2=['George','Ram', 'shyam']
    output=list1
    for j in list2:
        for i in list1:
            if str(j)!=str(i):
                output=output+[j]
    print(output)
```

But, it is wrong. Please help me know how to proceed for above problem! I am a noob in programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the final list should keep the original items order or does not matter?

Comment: What output do you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
list1=['ALEX', 'George', 'shyam']
list2=['George','Ram', 'shyam']
res = list1.copy()

for el in list2:
    if el not in res:
        res.append(el)

print(res)
```

Comment: This will work and keep the original item's order, at the cost of making extra copy.

Answer (score 0):

To combine two list use this:

```py
list1 = ['ALEX', 'George', 'shyam']
list2 = ['George','Ram', 'shyam']
resultList= list(set(list1 ) | set(list2))
print(resultList)
```

**Output**:
`['shyam', 'George', 'ALEX', 'Ram']`

Comment: This works but it will lose all the original order - if that's not required, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Sets can not have duplicates. So converting a list to a set and back to a list gets rid of all duplicates.  So add up your lists and convert the larger list to a set:

```
list1= ['ALEX', 'George', 'shyam']
list2= ['George','Ram', 'shyam']
result = set(list1 + list2)
print(list(result))

#prints ['Ram', 'George', 'ALEX', 'shyam']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the same order as stated in question

```
list1= ['ALEX', 'George', 'shyam']

list2= ['George','Ram', 'shyam']

#output=['Alex', 'George','Shyam','Ram']

output=[x.capitalize() for x in list1] # Copy list but capitalize each string e.g. ALEX -> Alex
for name in list2: # iterate through list2
    if name.capitalize() not in output: # if it is not already in output, append it
        output.append(name)
        
print(output)
```